# Disable close button of console window

Tags: python, windows, button, console

I want to control usage of the `[X]` button (the exit window button), which is generally present in the top-right corner when running a console-based `Python` application. I will be providing an in-program call to: `sys.exit()` when required. I know there is a similar option available even for `Java` `GUI` programming.

[image]

Comment: @SarveshEB Which type of terminal are you using?

Comment: @matsjoyce Just the default. This is how mine looks: [link](http://i.imgur.com/f50S3N7.png?1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
import win32console, win32gui, win32con
hwnd = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
if hwnd:
   hMenu = win32gui.GetSystemMenu(hwnd, 0)
   if hMenu:
       win32gui.DeleteMenu(hMenu, win32con.SC_CLOSE, win32con.MF_BYCOMMAND)
```

It requires the pywin32 modules to be installed. Note: I have not tested this, as I haven't got access to a Windows machine ATM.

References:

- [How can I prevent my program from closing when a console window it opens is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20236791/3946766)
- [How to use win32 API's with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025029/how-to-use-win32-apis-with-python)